# Sending same key headers as separate in httpClient in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.8

I need to send an HTTP request with a list of custom headers. Those headers could have duplicate keys with different values. I'm working in a .NET Framework project.

So far, I've tried using HttpClient and adding same key headers:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:8080/api/test");
    request.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "key1=value1; key2=value2; Path=/;");
    request.Headers.Add("Another-Key", "value1");
    request.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "key3=value3; Path=/;"); 
    await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

**Note**: it doesn't have to be a `Set-Cookie` header specifically as in the example, it could be any duplicate header key.

But when reading those headers on server-side, header value shows up as different values concatenated and separated with a comma:

```
Set-Cookie:key1=value1; key2=value2; Path=/;, key3=value3; Path=/;
```

And I specifically want the server-side to receive an array of values, so it should be

```
"Set-Cookie": ["key1=value1; key2=value2; Path=/;","key3=value3; Path=/;"]
```

The desired behaviour on server-side can be achieved with a CURL request:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/test' --header 'Set-Cookie: key1=value1; key2=value2; Path=/;' --header 'Another-Key: value1' --header 'Set-Cookie: key3=value3; Path=/;'
```

But I cannot replicate this type of behaviour for .NET request headers. I've also tried using `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest`, but both of those produced single, comma-separated string.

Is there a way to send multiple same key headers with different values as an array of values, instead of a single joined string of multiple values?

EDIT:

For server-side testing the `IHttpContextAccessor` interface is used. It is injected in a service that is used for testing and reading headers.

```
var headers = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
```

The problem is that for production purposes a third-party server will be used, and it cannot be modified in any way and it specifically requires array of values for same key headers.

Comment: Could you please share with us how do you read the headers on server-side?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpRequest` are different.

---

Whenever you are creating an `HttpClient` request then you are using a `HttpRequestMessage` object.

```
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://test.com")
{
    Headers =
    {
        { "A", "A" },
        { "A", "B" }
    }
};
```

The above code is totally fine since the `Headers` property defined as a `HttpRequestHeaders` which is derived from the `HttpHeaders` class:

```
public abstract class HttpHeaders : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,IEnumerable<string>>>
```

As you can see it is defined as a series of key value pairs where the key is a string and the value is a series of strings.

---

Whenever you access the `Request` of the `HttpContext` then you are not working with the `HttpRequestMessage` type rather than the `HttpRequest`.

The `HttpRequest`'s `Headers` property is defined as a `NameValueCollection` which is derived from the `NameObjectCollectionBase` class:

```
public abstract class NameObjectCollectionBase : ICollection, IDeserializationCallback, ISerializable
```

As the documentation highlights

> Provides the abstract base class for a collection of associated `String` keys and `Object` values that can be accessed either with the key or with the index

the value is a single object, not a series of objects. So, the following code will result in an `ArgumentException` (*An item with the same key has already been added*):

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("A", "A");
httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("A", "B");
```

---

In order to support multi value for the same key Microsoft simply string concatenated the values. That's what your experiment verifies as well.

Comment: [Related dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rH9SD2)